# почему папка vendor оказывается в корне сервера?

Tags: php, битрикс, composer

мне нужно установить зависимости composer,но после команды composer install папка vendor почему то оказывается в папке root,а не в нужно мне /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/vendor,установку делал из /home/bitrix/

Comment: `cd /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/` `composer init` так пробовали?)

Comment: не пробовал,мне просто нужен copmoser,json и vendor в разных папках

Comment: Нужно открыть и читать доку по композеру: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir